# Como hago para que una fila de un Treeview se vea completa cuando uno de los datos abarcan multiples lineas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual me dedico a crear un treeview cuyos valores abarcan varias líneas.

```
from tkinter import ttk

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=(0,))
tree.column("#0", width=0)
tree.column(0, width=100)

tree.insert("", "end", values=("text1\ntext2",))
tree.insert("", "end", values=("text3",))

tree.pack()
```

Sin embargo, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como supongo podrán ver, el contenido de la segunda fila tapa parte del contenido de la primera.

Buscando por Google, me hayé con esta pregunta de SO en ingles cuyas respuestas son lo más cercano a lo que busco: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957845/ttk-treeview-cant-change-row-height/26962663.

Sin embargo, lo que quiero lograr es que cada fila tenga una altura distinta que depende de la cantidad de líneas que contiene el texto. No encontré ninguna pagina que hable de eso buscando en Google.

Lo que quiero lograr es que el treeview se vea así

[image]

Alguien tiene alguna idea para poder lograr lo que busco?

Comment: Ósea quieres que el tamaño se ajuste al contenido, verdad?

Comment: Exactamente @Christian

Answer (score 1):

## Solución exacta

Lograr exactamente esto:

[image: Ejemplo usuario]

No es posible con la implementación actual de Treeview *(diciembre 2021)*

## Alternativa similar

Lo máximo que se puede lograr es construir una altura dinámica para las filas, pero no puede ser individual, es decir, esta altura será la misma para todas las celdas.
Suponiendo que configuras la fuente con

```
Font(family="Arial", size=10)
```

Luego puedes obtener la altura de un "renglón" usando:

```
lineheight = font.metrics()['linespace']
```

Ya solo necesitarías saber cuántos renglones tienes

```
def getLines(rows):
    lines = 1
    for row in rows:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.count('\n')>=lines:
                lines = cell.count('\n') + 1
                print("lines"+str(lines))
    return lines
```

Y ahora puedes configurar la altura basándote en la altura de la línea y la cantidad de las mismas

```
ttk.Style().configure('Treeview', font=font, rowheight=round(lineheight*lines))
```

De este modo obtendrías un resultado así:

[image: Treeview]

Y cambiando la fuente, el tamaño y el contenido, se adaptaría automáticamente a la altura mínima requerida:

[image: Treeview Verdana 20px]

## Código funcionando

Me tomé el atrevimiento de modificar algunas cuestiones.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

def getLines(rows):
    lines = 1
    for row in rows:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.count('\n')>=lines:
                lines = cell.count('\n') + 1
    return lines

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x600")

font = Font(family="Times New Roman", size=11)
lineheight = font.metrics()['linespace']
columns = ("A", "B")
rows = (("dato", "text1\ntext2"),("dato2", "text3"))
lines = getLines(rows)
ttk.Style().configure('Treeview', font=font, rowheight=round(lineheight*lines))
tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=columns, show="headings")
tree.column("A", width=100)
tree.column("B", width=100)
tree.heading("A", text="A")
tree.heading("B", text="B")
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=rows[0])
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=rows[1])
tree.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta c: Conocía esa alternativa, pero modifica el alto de todas las filas. Estaré esperando una respuesta que haga lo que busco. Igual tendré en cuenta la posibilidad de que no esté implementado nada similar. Nuevamente agradesco la respuesta.

Comment: No está implementado, si es crucial puedes colaborar en la implementación del mismo: [tkinter](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/tkinter)
Asegúrate de leer [Contributing to python](https://github.com/python/cpython#contributing-to-cpython) antes de hacerlo. También puedes unirte a la [mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman3/lists/python-ideas.python.org/) para elevar tu necesidad si es crítica y piensas que puede llegar a ganar tracción si no logras implementarla por tu cuenta.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos!